# Extract information from a 3-D graph

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I used the `plot3` method for creating a 3-D graph. Now I want to extract all the points with *z* > 0.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to have the data used to make the plot; if you have them directly, that is the simple case.  If not - for example, if you have a plot from some other script, or a figure file saved by someone else that you're just loading - you can get the data from the plot like this:

```
%# make sure the plot is the current axes object by clicking on it
%# or else use the actual axes handle instead of gca
X = get(gca,'xdata');
Y = get(gca,'ydata');
Z = get(gca,'zdata');
```

Next, use logical indexing:

```
index = Z > 0;
X_of_interest = X(index);
Y_of_interest = Y(index);
Z_of_interest = Z(index);
```

The new variables contain the `X,Y,Z` values of all points where the condition `Z>0` is true.

Comment: after I add these 4 lines to my code, MATLAB gives me this  error : 'Undefined Function Or Variable Z'.

Comment: You need to replace `X`,`Y`,`Z` with whatever those variables are called in your code.